# How to get raw php content?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get file content from a php file.

```
$content = file_get_contents('test.php');
var_dump($content);

//outputs
addUser();
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$client->addUser();
```

Why is **file_get_contents** removing **$client->** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably not removing anything, but you're reading the result in a browser, and the browser thinks that anything between a `<` and a `>` is a html tag.

Use the "view source" function in your browser to see the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 HTML brackets `<>`

Try this

```
echo htmlentites($content);
```